# Specific permissions required to run exchange 2010 powershell commands

Tags: powershell, permissions, exchange-server-2010

The helpdesk will be using a script I wrote to set out of office replies and to modify folder permissions but are running into permission issues using them. Is there any resource that would indicate what permissions each powershell command in the exchange cmdlet takes to be able to be ran? Failing that does anyone know the specific permissions needed to set OoO and modify folder permissions?

I did find [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638132%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) that gives specific roles needed to do various things but it's not quite what I'm looking for. These roles give access to far more than what we need.

EDIT: The Auto Reply role is all that is required to set allow use of the Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration. Looking into the others still.

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be as granular as the roles get.

If you want to restrict them further, you can set up one or more remote sessions they can connect to that use a delegated account that is an Exchange role member, and constrain the session to just being able to run your script.